# Minimum RF power for usable operation of mixer

Tags: power, rf, mixer

I am working on some down conversion process. I will have an LO of 410 MHz, an RF of 400 MHz. And I will use MAX2682 400-2500 MHz downconverter mixer IC from Maxim Integrated. LO power will be about 2 dBm.

My question is, what is the minimum RF input power for the mixer to produce the IF properly. In the datasheet, in the AC characteristics section, RF=-25 dBm is mentioned.

But I cannot figure out what the minimum RF power can be. Given, I do not have very much knowledge about mixers.

Is there any way of figuring it out? Or is there any lower limit at all (unless it is so low not to give an output sufficient to drive the following stages).

Here is a link to the MAX2682 datasheet:

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2680-MAX2682.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A mixer introduce a "Conversion Power Gain" within its operation.
Some datas are given in the datasheet, page 2
for example :
@ RF = 400MHz, LO = 445MHz, IF = 45MHz -> there "will be" 7.3 db gain.
It is not the highest possible. But is enough for having good low noise figure. The first stage is essential.

The usable RFin power level received and usable (in noise) depend mostly of the "IF amplifier".
If this amplifier is good, you will have a great sensitivity.

But as with all mixers, you have to deal with the non-linearities of this part (See the IP3 specification, as high as possible). So frequencies of operation must be choosen carefully.

For example, the first mixer in an "RF spectrum analyser" (0.1-1800 MHz old analog technology) was an up-converter as first stage (LO 2.2 GHz - 4 GHz), above usefull band) followed by an tuned amplifier @ 2.2GHz. Then first bandpass filters were choosen at 2.2 GHz ... After that, there was 2 down-converters (100 MHz, 10 MHz) each followed by tuned amplifiers. At least, at 10 MHz IF, other filters would be choosen down to 10 Hz ... with some other filters after "decoding" at 0.1 Hz bandwith.
The sensitivity was as low as -120 dbm (lowest then microvolt ...) for very low bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you. I have to learn a lot about mixers. But what I understand from your answer, if I can do well with the IF amplification stage, -90 to -100 dBm sensitivity would not be very hard. Thanks.

Comment: Choose frequency for IF filters that can give you standard components and well known. One IF can give 40-60 db, perhaps more (80 db) if very good screening. 10.7 MHz for components for FM , 455 kHz used AM, some others around 40 MHz and perhaps even 70 MHz. Use allready made IF if you can find some. If you can, use 2 IF frequencies. It will be more easy.

Comment: Use APPCAD from Avago Tecnologies to find spurs.

Comment: Here is also a good choice   https://www.rf-microwave.com/en/nbp/nmp/21-4-mhz-if-amplifier-module-for-fm-receivers/if-21.4/

Comment: Here also a good information about IP3 how and use ...  
   https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/5/5429.html

Comment: Thank you friend, lots of things. I will get back to you in time.